# Show data from Sql file in to jupiter notebook using DF

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to show data from SQL file to Jupiter notebook there is an issue going on when I use csv statement it is showing the data but when I use another statement for SQL it's not working it's a large file around containing 3.5 million records

```
import os 
import dnslib
import pandas as pd 
import numpy

import glob 
print(glob.glob("/home/imran/Dailer/"))
print (glob.glob("/home/imran/"))
['/home/imran/Dailer/vicidial_mysqli_errors.txt']
```

This code is working so far but its not working at all when I import another library and issue a new statement than the other statement is working perfectly.

```
#df = pd.read_csv('/home/imran/Documents/api/passwords.csv')
df = pd.read_sql('/home/imran/Documents/Hacked/an.sql')

df.head()
```

Error

```
#df = pd.read_csv('/home/imran/Documents/api/passwords.csv')
df = pd.read_sql('/home/imran/Documents/Hacked/an.sql')

df.head()
```

I am trying to show that are from asql file into Jupiter notebook
so i can  clean junt from that

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your question?